# find all strings from list which matches with given few alphabets

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I am building a simple function to search through some data from the list.
I am trying to search string from list matches some characters from `start of string`.

Like :-

```
my_list = ["com truise", "bill james", "bill bates", "bustin jeiber"]

def search_from_list(searched_word):
    for word in my_list:
        if searched_word == word:
            print("Matched")
            print("All words" + __full_word_that_matched__)

search_from_list("bi")
```

and if user calls the function with argument `"bi"` then I am trying to get strings which matched that string `"bi"` like :-

```
["bill james", "bill bates"]
```

But it is not working, I have tried many methods like :-

```
def search_from_list(searched_word):
    my_list = ["com truise", "bill james", "bill bates", "bustin jeiber"]

    print re.findall(r"(?=("+'|'.join(my_list)+r"))", searched_word)

searched_word("bi")
```

> But it returned empty

then I tried

```
def search_from_list(searched_word):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', searched_word)
    return [word for word in words if word in my_list]

n = search_from_list("bi")
```

> It also showed me empty list

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = ...

def search_from_list(substring):
    return [string for string in my_list if substring in string]
```

Answer (score 0):

with regular expression

```
import re
my_list = ["com truise", "bill james", "bill bates", "bustin jeiber"]

def search_from_list(searched_word):
    return [word for word in my_list if re.match(searched_word, word)]

print(search_from_list("bi"))
```